# chaining multiple calls in request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

How to chain multiple `then` with respective `catch` in expressjs routing.

My current use case is as part of `multupart form` update i need to upload image to cloud and update the detail through API and then delete previous Image.
There are 3 different Calls made. I'm getting `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` if there is any error. Looks like `res.json` and `next` is creating some issue

1. Is it preferred to use below approach  to my scenario ?

   ```
   var rp  = require('request-promise');
   var multer  = require('multer');
   var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
   var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

   app.post('/api/update-details', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next){

      function uploadImage(){
          //uploadToCloud is a dummy function to denote fileupload
          uploadToCloudApi(function(err,data){
              if(err) {
                   res.json({'msg': 'Image Upload Failed'})
              }

          })
      }


      function updateDetails(){
         updateApi(function(err,data){
              if(err) {
                   res.json({'msg': 'Image Upload Failed'})
              }

          })
      }

      function deletePreviousImage(){
           deleteFromCloudApi(function(err,data){
              if(err) {
                  log.error(err);
              }

          })
          next();
      }

      function updateSiteError(){

      }

      var options = { // url and other options };
       rp(options)
           .then(uploadImage)
           .then(updateDetails)
           .then(deletePreviousImage)
           .catch(updateSiteError); // How to write proper catch methods for each function ?


   })
   ```

Comment: If I understand right you're showing us a code that is different from what you're trying, but not the code you're trying. Hard to help you like that.

Comment: `javascript` at Question does not appear to `return` a `Promise` or value from `uploadImage`, `uploadDetails`, `deletePreviousImage` function calls? `updateSiteError` is not defined?